How to configure how many ticks Upgrade to 4
I upgraded from ChartJs 2 to 4.
The layout and ticks are still not as before.
This is a comparision between the old one version 2 (on top), and the new one version 4 at the bottom


And this is another example:
version 2

version 4

This is my code for chart configuration:
options: {
        legend: { display: false },
        responsive: false,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
          x: {
              type: "time",
              distribution: "timeseries",
              time: { parser: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm", tooltipFormat: "ll" },
              ticks: {
                source: "data",
                maxRotation: 90,
                minRotation: 90,
                autoSkip: false
              }
            },
          y: { ticks: { beginAtZero: true, major: { enabled: true } , autoSkip: false } }
        },
        tooltips: {
          callbacks: {
            label: this.label || defaultLabel
          }
        },
      }

And this is the shared configuration for each Line dataset:
{
data: [],
  backgroundColor: "#2bb2e7",
  borderColor: "#2bb2e7",
  color: '#000',
  fill: false,
  label: "",
  pointRadius: 5,
  pointHoverRadius: 20,
  borderWidth: 3,
  cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone',
  tension: 0.4
}

the question is:
How to control how many ticks showing on the "Y" axe (version 2 is better auto-calculating how many ticks)?

SO is a question and answer site. Note that question is singular, not plural. If you have multiple questions, they need to be in separate posts. For more information about how the site works, see the [help].

I removed the other two questions

You can adjust the number of ticks you need by using stepSize and maxTicksLimit.
For reference, please check the definition here:
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/api/#radialtickoptions
options: {
  legend: { display: false },
  responsive: false,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  scales: {
    x: {
      type: "time",
      distribution: "timeseries",
      time: { 
        parser: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm", 
        tooltipFormat: "ll" 
      },
      ticks: {
        source: "data",
        maxRotation: 90,
        minRotation: 90,
        autoSkip: false
      }
    },
    y: { 
      ticks: { 
        beginAtZero: true, 
        major: { enabled: true }, 
        autoSkip: false,
        stepSize: 5,  // Set the interval for Y-axis ticks
        maxTicksLimit: 100,  // Set the maximum number of ticks displayed
        suggestedMax: 100,  // Suggest the maximum value for Y-axis
        suggestedMin: 0  // Suggest the minimum value for Y-axis
      } 
    }
  },
  tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
      label: this.label || defaultLabel
    }
  },
}

